# Non-Classification outputs in a classification problem

Tags: deep-learning, classification, binary-classification

maybe this is a very stupid question, so please excuse me as I am a total beginner in Machine learning.

I have a dataset divided into X (shape: 10000, 599), Y(shape: 10000,). Y is simply zero or one. I am getting good accuracy and validation accuracy for my model. However when I am predicting Y using testX, I am getting all kinds of values between zero and 1. Most are very close to zero or one. But still, this is not exactly a classification output, is it? Or am I doing something wrong?

My model:

```
# create model
model = Sequential()
model.add(Dense(60,input_dim = trainX.shape[1], activation = 'relu'))
model.add(Dense(30,activation = 'relu'))
model.add(Dense(1,activation = 'sigmoid'))
# Compile model
model.compile(loss='binary_crossentropy', optimizer='adam', metrics = 'accuracy')

history = model.fit(trainX,trainY, epochs = 200,batch_size = 128, validation_data = (valX,valY))
```

Comment: You are using a sigmoid activation for your last dense layer, meaning that all values will be between 0 and 1 so the result you are seeing is expected. If you want a larger/other range of values you would need to change the activation for the last layer.

Comment: I deduced that this might be the issue. So what should I be using to get either zero or one values? Shoud I even be getting binary values, or just a probability distribution? It's my first time working with classification problems.

Comment: I am not too familiar with tensorflow/keras, but if the `predict` method is also giving you probabilities you should use a threshold yourself to convert those probabilities those 0/1 values.

Comment: Okay, got it, thanks!

Comment: The model intentionally returns probability values, not hard classifications. Consider evaluating those probability values: [Link 1](https://www.fharrell.com/post/class-damage/) [Link 2](https://www.fharrell.com/post/classification/). Since your probability values are all close to $0$ or $1$, you might be in one of these high signal-to-noise situations Harrell describes, but his two blog posts I linked still make for good reading.